# ISO 8583 c library unpack message

Tags: c, iso8583

I want to know how I can unpack an ISO 8583 message using [DL ISO-8583 Library](http://www.oscarsanderson.com/iso-8583/) (C Language) written by oscarsanderson?
For example, if I have such message: Here's my code

```
#include "dl_iso8583.h"
#include "dl_iso8583_defs_1993.h"
#include "dl_output.h" // for 'DL_OUTPUT_Hex'

#define ISOHEADER 4
#define ISOHEADERSTR "%04d"

int main ( void )
{
    DL_ISO8583_HANDLER isoHandler;
    DL_ISO8583_MSG     isoMsg;
    DL_UINT8           packBuf[1000];
    DL_UINT16          packedSize;
    char msg[]="0210323A40010A4180103800000000000000000420050805011392120805042004225132072000001000000115604000800411 163011511463331563GBAAASDD ERRR 1300101B54391001000017654350000000000090300000268410000000300000000000000898100009431000000000000000000 000000000000000036000299";

    unsigned short iso_req_size,iso_resp_size;
    char iso_header[ISOHEADER+1];
     char iso_req_buf[10000];
     char iso_resp_buf[10000];

    /* get ISO-8583 1993 handler */
    DL_ISO8583_DEFS_1993_GetHandler(&isoHandler);
    DL_ISO8583_MSG_Init(NULL,0,&isoMsg);

    // Unpack message
    DL_ISO8583_MSG_Init(NULL,0,&isoMsg);

    (void)DL_ISO8583_MSG_Unpack(&isoHandler,msg,strlen(msg),&isoMsg);
    DL_ISO8583_MSG_Dump(stdout,NULL,&isoHandler,&isoMsg);
    DL_ISO8583_MSG_Free(&isoMsg);

    return 0;

}
```

I want to retrieve those fields when unpacking the message:

```
    [000]:    210
    [003]:    380000
    [004]:    000000000000
    [007]:    0420050805
    [011]:    011392
    [012]:    120805
    [013]:    0420
    [015]:    0422
    [018]:    5132
    [039]:    00
    [049]:    000
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did it work? How *didn't* it work? Is there something specific that you get stuck on? I also recommend you read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I might have formatted `msg` incorrectly.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' - nope, it's fine

Comment: Your `char msg[]` is not a valid ISO8583 message. I think you meant `char msg[] = "\x02\x10\x03"`...  . And don't use `strlen`, this is not a string.

Comment: You are right  Matt McNabb my message was not right but the problem i have is how to send \00 in a socket because once i write "\x02\x00\x03" and i send through the socket i am receiving \5c00 instead of \00.any idea? i am using m2m switch from morocco

Answer (score 2):

you must convert your msg from hex format to binary.
like this

```
binMsg[0]=0x02
binMsg[1]=0x10
binMsg[2]=0x32
binMsg[3]=0x3A
binMsg[4]=0x40
```

untel last bites.

and use :

```
(void)DL_ISO8583_MSG_Unpack(&isoHandler,binMsg,strlen(msg)/2,&isoMsg);
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge DL iso 8583 library written by oscarsanderson does not work with hexadecimal bitmap.So first you need to convert hexadecimal bitmap to binary then you need to know the properties of iso structure fields(i.e element type (numeric,binary,alphanumeric,ascii etc),length,length type(fixed length or variable length)).After knowing this you can retrieve
the fields